# VBA- Dropown to navigate to a sheet/workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  If ComboBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then Sheets(ComboBox1.Text).Select
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If ComboBox1.ListCount <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
        ComboBox1.Clear
        For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            ComboBox1.AddItem xSheet.Name
        Next xSheet
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is what I have So far. At the moment it shows all my workbooks/sheets where as I only want it to show 10 specific sheets.

Comment: We have no clue how your workbook is setup so there is no way we can really provide any solutions other than, add the 10 manually.   I you want to provide a bit more context on how the 10 sheets are named or some other way to distinguish them from the others then you will get a more robust answer.

Comment: Hi @Sorceri , For example they are name Part C (B), Part C (D), Part C (E).... Part C (M)

Comment: I don't mind adding them manually only if i knew how to do it

Comment: The other sheets are Part A, Part B and Part D. I dont want them in the dropdown

Comment: so all the sheets you want to add have a ( in them and all the ones you don't want to add do not have a ( in them, correct?... ` ComboBox1.AddItem  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part C (B)")`

Comment: Are you able to tell me the exact name for all the sheets and which ones you want listed?

Comment: @Ricardo A the sheet names are
Part C (B), Part C (D), Part C (E), Part C (D), Part C (E), Part C (F), Part C (G), Part C (H), Part C (J), Part C (K) Part C (L), Part C (M)

Comment: Yes @Sorceri that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  If ComboBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then Sheets(ComboBox1.Text).Select
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If ComboBox1.ListCount <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
        ComboBox1.Clear
        For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If xSheet.Name Like "Part C (*" Then ComboBox1.AddItem xSheet.Name
        Next xSheet
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Specific Sheet Names on a Switch: (requested by OP)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If ComboBox1.ListCount <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
        ComboBox1.Clear
        For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            Select Case xSheet.Name
                Case "Part C (B)", "Part C (D)", "Part C (E)", "Part C (F)", "Part C (G)", _
                    "Part C (H)", "Part C (J)", "Part C (K)", "Part C (L)", "Part C (K)"
                    ComboBox1.AddItem xSheet.Name
            End Select
        Next xSheet
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You can add, remove sheet names, if you decide to break the line, do not forget to use the "_" symbol to break it. (very common mistake)

Comment: Thanks Man! Do you have a solution that includes specifc names of the sheet?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include specific sheet names.

Comment: can you tell me how to do default value for the Combo Box?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this comment:

> "The other sheets are Part A, Part B and Part D. I dont want them in
>   the dropdown"

This will work

```
    For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case xSheet.Name
            Case Is = "Part A", "Part B", "Part D"
            Case Else
                ComboBox1.AddItem xSheet.Name
        End Select
    Next xSheet
```

You can easily modify the Select Case statement to create more conditions.

You could also do something more complex like below for more pattern matching:

```
Select Case Instr(xSheet.Name, "(")
    Case Is > 0: ComboBox1.AddItem xSheet.Name
End Select
```

Comment: Thank although it is only not showing "Part A". Part B and D are still showing

Comment: @RealHelper - See my edited answer and try again. I forgot "<>" does not work well for multiple statements in `Case`